# Image gallery code issue

Tags: html, css, image, gallery

I created this image gallery that an image is revealed on hovering but the revealed image is in a different place in every computer/browser i open it in but for the life of me I can't figure out why.

I just want the revealed image to appear in the middle without being on top of other images but when i get it to that setting on one computer it looks different on another.

I'm new to coding so I really hope someone helps. Here's the link to my codepen: [image gallery](http://codepen.io/zenturtle/pen/ezDGC)

```
  [1]: http://codepen.io/zenturtle/pen/ezDGC
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. We'd like to help you - but we don't want to click out to a different site to do it. Also - links go stale over time, and we want questions on stack overflow to last forever. So: please *edit your question* and add all the *relevant* code there. Also tell us: what have you tried to fix it - what have you researched and why were the results unsatisfactory?

Answer (score 0):

For consistent placement, you need to give the `#perimeter` div `position: relative`, so that the positioning of the large images will always be in relation to the containing div, which has a fixed width. Otherwise, the positioning is in relation to the browser/viewport, meaning that it will be different depending on the size/width of the browser.

```
#perimeter {position: relative;}
```

You will probably have to adjust all of the large image coordinates now. There are more efficient ways to do this, though. You should be able to place all of those images with one CSS rule, rather than separate ones for each image.

Comment: Thank you so much, I changed the code and it looks great on my computer, I'm going to test it out tomorrow on another one. I would love to learn a more efficient way of doing it could you please share?

Comment: Perhaps with some motivation. :-)

Comment: not sure what you mean, sorry. But thanks again for the tip :)